# Broken links in the community-made Tome of Battle Build Compendium

Tags: dnd-3.5e, online-resources

I'm looking for a build for a new Swordsage character and I bumped into the [Tome of Battle Build Compendium](http://community.wizards.com/forum/previous-editions-character-optimization/threads/1074271), but all of the links are broken. As I read, there was some changing in the site forum engine and the links were lost at that time. Does anyone have a backup or a currently working copy?

Comment: As your problem is a general problem that's true for all of WotC's 3.5e pages, I'm removing [tag:tome-of-battle], hoping to attract more people.